# Does RegisterHotKey not working a separate thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, registerhotkey

I have a thread executing certain things and right at the end it's supposed to bind my F key as a global hotkey, I've been unable to get this to work, any insight as to what I'm doing wrong OR if RegisterHotKey is not functioning cause of my thread?

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool RegisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys fsModifiers, Keys vk);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UnregisterHotKey(IntPtr hWnd, int id);

private const int WmHotKey = 0x0312;

private void onLoad()
{
   //RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.None, Keys.F); // This works
}

private void OnSeparateThread()
{
   // This gets called by a separate thread, in the full version of the code more stuff
   // happen here, which does get executed.
   RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, 0, System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys.None, Keys.F); // Does not bind
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
   if (m.Msg == WmHotKey)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Test me!");
   }
   base.WndProc( ref m );
}
```

Edit: Naturally I'm not binding both of these at the same time, one is always commented out.

Comment: Documentation is not just for decoration. [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx): "This function cannot associate a hot key with a window created by another thread."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Originally a comment, but it does answer the question as posed):

From MSDN, [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> This function cannot associate a hot key with a window created by another thread.

So, simple answer is no.